# Rendering to texture - ClearRenderTargetView() works, but none objects are rendered to texture (rendering to screen works fine)

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, directx-11, render-to-texture

I try to render the scene to texture which should be then displayed in corner of the screen.

I though that I can do that this way:

1. Render the scene (my `Engine::render()` method that will set shaders and make draw calls) - **works ok**.
2. Change render target to the texture.
3. Render the scene again - **does not work.** The `context->ClearRenderTargetView(texture->getRenderTargetView(), { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } )` **does** set my texture to red color (for scene in step 1. I use different color), but **none** objects are being rendered on it.
4. Change render target back to original.
5. Render the scene for the last time, with rectangle at corner that has the texture I've rendered in step 3. - **works ok**. I see the scene, the little rectangle in the corner too. The problem is, it's just red (something went wrong with rendering in step 3., I guess).

The result (there should be "image in image" instead of red rectangle):
[image]

The code for steps 2. - 4.:

```
context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &textureRenderTargetView, depthStencilView); 
float bg[4] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
context->ClearRenderTargetView(textureRenderTargetView, bg); //backgroundColor - red, green, blue, alpha
render();
context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &myRenderTargetView, depthStencilView); //bind  render target back to previous value (not to texture)
```

The `render()` method does not change (**it works in step 1., why it doesn't work when I render to texture?**) and ends with `swapChain->Present(0, 0)`.

I know that `ClearRenderTargetView` affects my texture (without it, it's doesn't change color to red). But the rest of rendering either do not output to it or there's another problem.

**Did I miss something?**

I create the texture, shader resource view and render target for it based on [this tutorial](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11RTT) (maybe there is an error in my `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`?):

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

//1. create render target

ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

//setup the texture description
//we will need to have this texture bound as a render target AND a shader resource
textureDesc.Width = size.getX();
textureDesc.Height = size.getY();
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

//create the texture
device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &textureRenderTarget);

//2. create render target view

//setup the description of the render target view.
renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

//create the render target view
device->CreateRenderTargetView(textureRenderTarget, &renderTargetViewDesc, &textureRenderTargetView);

//3. create shader resource view

//setup the description of the shader resource view.
shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

//create the shader resource view.
device->CreateShaderResourceView(textureRenderTarget, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &texture);
```

The depth buffer:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = sampleCount;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = maxQualityLevel;
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
```

And here goes the swap chain:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
sd.BufferCount = 1;
sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator; //60
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator; //1
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.OutputWindow = *hwnd;
sd.SampleDesc.Count = sampleCount; //1 (and 0 for quality) to turn off multisampling
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = maxQualityLevel;
sd.Windowed = fullScreen ? FALSE : TRUE;
sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH; //allow full-screen switchin

// Set the scan line ordering and scaling to unspecified.
sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
// Discard the back buffer contents after presenting.
sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
```

I create the default render target view that way:

```
//create a render target view
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
result = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
ERROR_HANDLE(SUCCEEDED(result), L"The swapChain->GetBuffer() failed.", MOD_GRAPHIC);

//Create the render target view with the back buffer pointer.
result = device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &myRenderTargetView);
```

Comment: Do you clear your `depthStencilView` in `render()`? Otherwise your scene would be rejected by the z test, because the depth values will be equal. In general, for such situations graphics debugger like NSight, Renderdoc, etc. comes in handy, which will let you analyze every rendering steps to look for the part which is not working.

Comment: I do use `context->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);` at the beginning of `render()`. If I render to screen, I get the correct output (I can see the animation of camera etc.), so I guess everything works between frames.

Comment: For debugging I use build-in Graphic Debugger (from Visual Studio). I can e.g. pick the pixel and get the info about what stages/draw calls affected it. The problem is, when I click on red rectangle it only shows that red texture was picked from resource and drew there (I see the debug of my 5. step / 3rd render call where I render with my texture and not the 3. step where I render to that texture - where I guess something went wrong).

Comment: This may help you as a guide http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut22.html however be aware that the web address may change.

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I actually use rastertek.com tutorials too sometimes. I managed to make my code works eventually. But I wonder why I cannot use anti-aliasing while rendering to texture (check my answer for details). I would be glad if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: Yes for Direct X his are decent. If you are trying to use OpenGL I will suggest http://www.marekknows.com his site shouldn't change I've been a member since 2008 or 2009. His tutorials are video based and his presentation for explain the code is very well done. He covers many different topics that are involved with designing a Game Engine. However at this point his use of different shading techniques is limited since we are still building the core components of his new Shader Engine. I highly recommend his site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, as @Gnietschow suggested, I have found an error:

> D3D11 ERROR:  ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets:
>
> The RenderTargetView at slot 0 is not compatable with the
>   DepthStencilView.  DepthStencilViews may only be used with
>   RenderTargetViews if the effective dimensions of the Views are equal,
>   as well as the Resource types, multisample count, and multisample
>   quality.
>
> The RenderTargetView at slot 0 has (w:1680,h:1050,as:1),   while the
>   Resource is a Texture2D with **(mc:1,mq:0)**.
>
> The DepthStencilView has
>   (w:1680,h:1050,as:1),   while the Resource is a Texture2D with
>   **(mc:8,mq:16)**.

So basically, my render target (texture) was not using anti-aliasing while my back buffer/depth buffer do.

I had to change `SampleDesc.Count` to `1` and `SampleDesc.Quality` to `0` in both `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` and `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` to match the values from texture to which I render. In other words I had to turn off anti-aliasing when rendering to texture.

I wonder, **why render to texture does not support anti-aliasing?** When I set `SampleDesc.Count` and `SampleDesc.Quality` to my standard values (`8` and `16`, those works fine on my GPU when rendering the scene) for my texture render target, the `device->CreateTexture2D(...)` fails with "invalid parameter" (even when I use those same values everywhere).

Comment: I think you are using too much samples, because for `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` you can only use at max 4 samples (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , jump to 'multisample')

Comment: @Gnietschow thank you :) So my option are: A) lower the samples values B) change format from `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`? Does it mean that "screen" (render target) do not use `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` (as it support `8` samples - I can render on it with `mc:8, mq:16`)?

Comment: Unless you're saving floating point data (e.g. for the position in a deferred renderer) you don't need such a big format. For simple color data as in your picture in picture case a simple 8 bit format like `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` would be enough. Moreover don't confuse the format with multisampling: the format defines which bit-size and order a specific texel has and multisampling, to put it simply, adds for each texel more texel of the same type. So you don't need to cover the needed space for multisampling in your format it will be done in the background for you.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I confuse something... but can I use `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` when my vertex layout use `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` for `POSITION` semantic and `DirectX::XMFLOAT3` to store it (vertex structure)? Also, pixel shader returns `float4` value.