# D3D11: Rendering (depth) to texture results in red square, normal rendering works

Tags: c++, directx-11, direct3d

I'm currently working on a D3D project and want to implement directional shadow mapping. I set everything up according to the [Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/create-depth-buffer-resource--view--and-sampler-state), but it just doesn't work.

I've created a 2D texture object, a depth stencil view and a shader resource view and set them up using the following descriptions:

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC shadowMapDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&shadowMapDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    shadowMapDesc.Width = width;
    shadowMapDesc.Height = height;
    shadowMapDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    shadowMapDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    shadowMapDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS;
    shadowMapDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    shadowMapDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    shadowMapDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    shadowMapDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    shadowMapDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    shadowMapDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    ID3D11Device& d3ddev = dev.getD3DDevice();

    uint32_t *initData = new uint32_t[width * height];
    ZeroMemory(initData, sizeof(uint32_t) * width * height);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    data.pSysMem = initData;
    data.SysMemPitch = sizeof(uint32_t) * width;
    data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    HRESULT hr = d3ddev.CreateTexture2D(&shadowMapDesc, &data, &texture_);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    hr = d3ddev.CreateDepthStencilView(texture_, &depthStencilViewDesc, &stencilView_);

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&shaderResourceViewDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

    hr = d3ddev.CreateShaderResourceView(texture_, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderView_);
```

Between these steps there is additional error checking, but all the create-functions return successfully. I then bind the texture, render my scene and unbind the texture using the following functions:

```
void D3DDepthTexture2D::bindAsTarget(D3DDevice& dev)
{
    dev.getDeviceContext().ClearDepthStencilView(stencilView_, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    // Bind target
    dev.getDeviceContext().OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, stencilView_);

    // Set viewport
    dev.setViewport(static_cast<float>(width_), static_cast<float>(height_), 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void D3DDepthTexture2D::unbindAsTarget(D3DDevice& dev, float width, float height)
{
    // Unbind target
    dev.resetRenderTarget();

    // Reset viewport
    dev.setViewport(width, height, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

My render-to-depth-texture routine basically looks like this (removing all the unnecessary details):

```
camera = buildCameraFromLight(light);
setCameraCBuffer(camera);
bindTexture();
activateShader();
for(Object j : objects) {setTransformationCBuffer(j); renderObject(j);}
deactivateShader();
unbindTexture();
```

Rendering the scene from the light's perspective to the normal render target (screen) results in the proper image (both the actual image and just rendering the depth values). I use a simple vertex shader that just transforms the vertices and a pixel shader that does nothing at all OR returns the depth values (I tried both, doesn't change anything about the end result since we don't care about the color buffer).

After clearing the texture and rendering to it, I render it onto a quad to my screen, but all I get is a red square - so the depth value is 1.0f, the value I've cleared the texture to. I'm really at a loss for what to do, I tried everything, implemented every possible solution from online tutorials or changed things around on my own, but nothing helps. Here's a list of all the things I already checked:

- All FAILED(hr)-calls return false, no error message is printed to the console
- I tested whether the geometry gets transformed properly by rendering the geometry and their depth values (z / w) to screen, which worked and looked correct
- I tested calculating the depth values in the fragment shader and rendering to a normal render target (basically trying to render my color buffer to texture) instead of a depth stencil texture, but that didn't work either, red square
- I tested different formats and format combinations for the shadow map and the views, which either caused the creation to fail or didn't change a thing
- I checked whether any call between setting and unsetting my texture as the render target during the render call resetted the depth stencil target to something else - not the case
- I debugged my texture-to-screen/quad rendering routine already and it works properly with other textures, so I am in fact seeing what the depth texture looks like
- I changed the geometry and camera perspective around to see whether that makes anything visible in the depth texture - it doesn't
- I came across [this similar StackOverflow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931194/rendering-to-texture-clearrendertargetview-works-but-none-objects-are-rende) and checked whether my default depth stencil buffer had the same dimensions, AA settings etc. as my texture - and it does (count 1, quality 0)

I really don't know what's up, I've been trying to debug this for hours and hours. I hope someone here can give me any advice on what I'm doing wrong or what I could try to fix this. I'm using C++11 with Direct3D11.

Note: I can't debug any of this using NSight or any Visual Studio tools since they don't seem to work properly with my system right now and I don't have any administrative rights to fix any of it. I just have to deal with it for now. I hope the given information and code samples are enough to provide a rough idea of what I could also try to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using RenderDoc to check what's really submitted to the API? It has pixel history and all the cool stuff for DX 11. I think it has portable version so you won't have to give administrative privileges.

Comment: If you could make a capture and share it here, it would be very helpful to answer your question. A capture is an .rdc file that you save after you've captured frame from the app.

Comment: Here's a link to build: https://renderdoc.org/builds, you want the latest portable build. Unzip it and follow documentation: https://renderdoc.org/docs/how/how_capture_frame.html

Comment: I'll check that out and report back next monday, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got NSight to work and debugged the whole thing with that. Turns out the depth texture was properly created and filled with the depth and stencil data and I just forgot that all the depth information is stored in the first channel - so I ignored the g and b data and used 1.0 for a and it worked. Using the g and b channels somehow made the whole thing red (maybe someone wants to add to this and explain why).

Debugging this got much easier once I could observe the texture that is present in the shader - I should've used a debugging tool like NSight or RenderDoc way earlier. Thanks to @EgorShkorov for the advice.